# reduction formula for $\int (x ^a +1)^{-n}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$a\in \mathbb{R}$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Consider : 
$$I_n(x)= \int \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{(1+x^a)^n} .$$

Find a relation between $I_n(x)$ and $I_{n+1}(x)$.

Comment: What kind of relation do you expect? How about $\cfrac{I_n'}{I_{n+1}'}=1+x^a$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$I_n(x)=\dfrac{x}{(1+x^{\alpha})^n}+\int nx\dfrac{ \cdot \alpha x^{\alpha-1}}{(1+x^{\alpha})^{n+1}} dx=\dfrac{x}{(1+x^{\alpha})^n}+n\alpha( I_n(x)-I_{n+1}(x))$$ By integrating by parts.

Comment: can you give me more details ? thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Let $u=\dfrac{1}{(1+x^a)^{n}}$ and $dv=dx$.